# I get a writing access violation of 0x00000... when trying to assign a value into my struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, access-violation

for part of a school lab I need to read in unique words and their corresponding count with a struct. I am new to structs so please bear with me. I am getting an access violation when I try to write the adress of the current word to the character pointer inside of the current instance of my struct. I have read that this is due to dereferencing a nullptr. I have tried to understand this, but I just don't get it. I have resized arrays just like this on regular char** arrays for accepting new words. I am at a loss, any help would be greatly appreciated. The input file used here is just random words separated by non letter characters but not - or , Here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;
using std::right;
using std::left;

using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;

const int BUFFER = 100; //I figure this buffer is big enough for any given word

struct Word_Count_STRUCT
{
    char* WORD = nullptr;
    int COUNT = 0;
};

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

    //Input for phrase
    ifstream iphrase;

    //Output to CSV (word count)
    ofstream o_count;

    //Word Exceptions
    ifstream xinWord;


    char wordbuffer[BUFFER] = { '\0' };
    char ch = 0;
    Word_Count_STRUCT** uniquewords = nullptr;
    Word_Count_STRUCT** temp = nullptr;

    int k = 0;
    int wordcount = 0;
    char* cword = nullptr; //Current Word
    bool NextWord_flag = false;
    bool interwordpunct = false;
    bool NewWord_flag = true;


    iphrase.open("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\henroE.txt");
    if (iphrase.is_open())
    {
        while (!iphrase.eof())
        {
            
            iphrase.get(ch);

            if (isalpha(ch) || ch == '\'' || ch == '-')
            {
                wordbuffer[k] = ch;
                ++k;
                NextWord_flag = true;

                if (ch == '\'' || ch == '-')
                    interwordpunct = true;
            }
            if ( (NextWord_flag == true) && (!isalpha(ch)) && (interwordpunct == false) )
            {
                k = 0;
                cword = new char[strlen(wordbuffer) + 1];
                strcpy(cword, wordbuffer);
                memset(wordbuffer, '\0', sizeof(wordbuffer));
                for (int i = 0; (i < wordcount) && (NewWord_flag == true); ++i)
                {
                    
                    int cmp = _stricmp(uniquewords[i]->WORD, cword);
                    if (cmp == 0)
                    {
                        NewWord_flag = false;
                        uniquewords[i]->COUNT++;
                        delete[] cword;
                    }
                }
                if (NewWord_flag == true)
                {
                    temp = new Word_Count_STRUCT * [wordcount + 1]();
                    for (int i = 0; i < wordcount; ++i)
                    {
                        temp[i] = uniquewords[i];
                    }
                    delete[] uniquewords;

                    temp[wordcount]->WORD = cword;
                    temp[wordcount]->COUNT++;
                    uniquewords = temp;
                    ++wordcount;
                    NextWord_flag = false;
                }
                interwordpunct = false;
                NewWord_flag = true;


            }

        }
}
```

I get an error on this line:

```
temp[wordcount]->WORD = cword;
```

I also get an error on the int value COUNT as well if I comment the line above it out. So I am guessing it is something with how I initialized the struct.
Worth noting that if I do not initialize this call:

```
temp = new Word_Count_STRUCT * [wordcount + 1]();
```

and instead just leave it as

```
temp = new Word_Count_STRUCT * [wordcount + 1];
```

I get another access violation but for reading instead of writing at 0xFFFFF...

At a loss, thank you for any help :)

Comment: Please make a [mcve] that includes your headers.  Don't make us guess how to compile your code.  What is a few lines of the `henroE.txt` file?

Comment: My apologies, I added headers, I am not sure at all where the problem could arise so I am not sure how to slim it down :(

Comment: What is the value of `wordcount`? I expect it is zero, otherwise accessing `uniquewords` (which is also null) would fail earlier. `temp[wordcount]`'s value is null. Please use a debugger and walk through your code line-by-line looking at the value of variables as the code executes.  We don't have your input file.

Comment: One approach is back up the program and then remove half of it. Compile, run, see if you still have the problem. If yes, remove half of what remains and repeat. If not focus your attentions on the removed half. It's a bit trickier than literally lopping the program in half, that almost certainly wouldn't compile, but a brute force *logical* halving  is still a good way to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a number of things wrong. First, using fixed-length character buffers instead of C++ strings is about 20 years out of date and WILL cause buffer overflow errors unless you are exceedingly careful.

But this is an issue:

```
                temp = new Word_Count_STRUCT * [wordcount + 1]();
                for (int i = 0; i < wordcount; ++i)
                {
                    temp[i] = uniquewords[i];
                }
                delete[] uniquewords;
```

But where did you allocate uniquewords? You declared it.

You also allocate cword outside a loop but the delete it inside a loop -- which seems really fishy, too.

But note that all you've allocated are pointers. I don't see you actually allocating the structure you're trying to put data in.

Comment: "But note that all you've allocated are pointers. I don't see you actually allocating the structure you're trying to put data in." Man, this is embarrassing, I really didn't think that through, I got my code working now, thank you, sir. I would really like to upvote your answer but my account is too new to do so. Thank you!